# How can I report custom events by visitor in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We use custom event tracking in our web application with Google Analytics to report user's behavior (for example - user clicks on key actions, client side errors, time measurements, etc.) 
Each time the Google Analytics code is run on the client, we set a custom variable at the Visitor session to set the actual username of the user.
How do you use Google Analytics to report a table of all the custom events by visitor? 
Our goal is to be able to have a storyline for each user, with all the events produced by the application correlated to its username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no standard reporting views in Google Analytics that will give you this full view by default.

The best way to do this is with Custom Reports: Create a flat table custom report that has the custom variable value as a dimension, and the custom event dimension you're interested as another dimension. Then, set the metrics you want (total or unique event hits, presumably), and set the filter to filter down to the specific event category or action you want to view against.

Below I have an API recommendations (from a previous version of this answer) for how to pull this, but it would be roughly the same for creating a custom report.

---

Depending on your exact needs, the API call would be structured something like:

**Metrics**: ga:totalEvents

**Dimensions**: ga:customVarValue1,ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel

**Filters**: gaEventCategory==Foo

Comment: Is this still the case in May 2013?

Comment: @PerQuestedAronsson No, actually, this wasn't a very good answer. I totally disregarded the best option here, Custom Reports. I've edited it. Let me know if it helps.